Can't edit single web part page
I need to show an embedded Power BI report in full width. Therefore I change a page under Communication Site by using PnP:
Set-PnPClientSidePage -Identity $PageName -LayoutType "SingleWebPartAppPage"

However, after change I cannot edit the page because the Edit button is hidden. The page become read only.
Is there anything I missed?

Sound's like it may have broke the site. You could always append ?Mode=Edit to the URL to enter edit mode.
